# Submitting form from interior (2nd level) pages

Tags: php, email, phpmailer

I have a contact form in the footer of my site that uses PHPMailer..so it shows up on all pages as it's part of the template. It works perfectly on "top" level pages i.e. www.mywebsite.com/index.html but on interior (or 2nd level pages, i.e. www.mywebsite.com/pricing/basic.html) it doesn't send. The console is saying that it cannot find "contact.php" file which is located in the root of my site directory.

I've tried adding "../contact.php" as the form action to move up a level but it still doesn't find it.

```php
<?php

/*
THIS FILE USES PHPMAILER INSTEAD OF THE PHP MAIL() FUNCTION
*/

use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;

require 'PHPMailer-master/vendor/autoload.php';

/*
*  CONFIGURE EVERYTHING HERE
*/

// an email address that will be in the From field of the email.
$fromEmail = 'xxxxxxxx';
$fromName = 'No Reply Email';

// an email address that will receive the email with the output of the form
$sendToEmail = 'xxxxxx';
$sendToName = 'New Contact Form Message';

// subject of the email
$subject = 'New message from contact form';

// form field names and their translations.
// array variable name => Text to appear in the email
$fields = array('name' => 'Name:', 'email' => 'Email:', 'message' => 'Message:');

// message that will be displayed when everything is OK :)
$okMessage = 'Successfully submitted - we will get back to you soon!';

// If something goes wrong, we will display this message.
$errorMessage = 'There was an error while submitting the form. Please try again later';

/*
*  LET'S DO THE SENDING
*/

// if you are not debugging and don't need error reporting, turn this off by error_reporting(0);
error_reporting(E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE);

try {

    if (count($_POST) == 0) throw new \Exception('Form is empty');
    $emailTextHtml .= "<h3>New message from xxxxx xxxxx:</h3><hr>";
    $emailTextHtml .= "<table>";

    foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {
        // If the field exists in the $fields array, include it in the email
        if (isset($fields[$key])) {
            $emailTextHtml .= "<tr><th>$fields[$key]</th><td>$value</td></tr>";
        }
    }
    $emailTextHtml .= "</table><hr>";
    $emailTextHtml .= "<p>Have a great day!<br><br>Sincerely,<br><br>xxxx xxxx</p>";

    $mail = new PHPMailer;

    $mail->setFrom($fromEmail, $fromName);
    $mail->addAddress($sendToEmail, $sendToName); // you can add more addresses by simply adding another line with $mail->addAddress();
    $mail->addReplyTo($_POST['email'], $_POST['name']);



    $mail->Subject = $subject;

    $mail->Body = $emailTextHtml;
    $mail->isHTML(true);
    //$mail->msgHTML($emailTextHtml); // this will also create a plain-text version of the HTML email, very handy


    if (!$mail->send()) {
        throw new \Exception('Email send failed. ' . $mail->ErrorInfo);
    }

    $responseArray = array('type' => 'success', 'message' => $okMessage);
} catch (\Exception $e) {
    // $responseArray = array('type' => 'warning', 'message' => $errorMessage);
    $responseArray = array('type' => 'warning', 'message' => $e->getMessage());
}


// if requested by AJAX request return JSON response
if (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) && strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) == 'xmlhttprequest') {
    $encoded = json_encode($responseArray);

    header('Content-Type: application/json');

    echo $encoded;
}
// else just display the message
else {
    echo $responseArray['message'];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like it's nothing to do with what's in this script, but about where it is loaded from. Try pointing your form action at an absolute path rather than a relative one, i.e. `action="/contact.php"` rather than a relative `action="contact.php"` or `action="../contact.php"`. That way it will always point at the same script regardless of where it is submitted from.

Separate from the issue you describe, this line looks suspicious:

```
require 'PHPMailer-master/vendor/autoload.php';
```

This suggests you may be using PHPMailer's own `composer.json` file; You should only use that if you're working *on* PHPMailer, and not just using it in your project. You would normally expect the `vendor` folder and `composer.json` file to be at the top level of your own project, and PHPMailer's files would have been put in `vendor/phpmailer` by composer - though you don't have to care about that because `vendor/autoload.php` will figure that out. Please read the readme for how to install PHPMailer in your own project using composer.